# Debian hangs on startup (NFS Common utilities: statd)

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

I am trying to configure my debian 6 machine to use DHCP. I have modified the `/etc/network/interfaces` to only contain:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

But when I reboot it hang at  `NFS Common utilities: statd` . After around 5 minutes comes to the login screen, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> /etc/network/interfaces **to only contain**:

You need the loopback interface.  Do not remove it.  Many pieces of software absolutely require it to operate correctly.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: So do I need both eth0 and lo? I did try to specify only lo but then I could not SSH to the machine-

Comment: This answered my post (I need both) http://askubuntu.com/questions/214170/whats-the-default-etc-network-interfaces