# debian server fails to initialize on login load and other related problems

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization, freeze

Very good day/afternoon/night, I have finally decided to expose my problem after trying several options, but unfortunately none of them is related to my issue. The case is that we have a debian server in use, which one day stopped booting. Here I attach the screenshot image that I made at that time. Just in that one it stays for hours and hours, having to force the shutdown.
[The exact moment during loading when the OS freezes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PtuJ.png)
I have tried with different linux live, with rescatux, with hiren's boot cd, and in all of them, as soon as I run the mount of the main partition, the next second it crashes and freezes. And I don't know what to do to revive it, that's why I turn to this website.
P.S.: I've seen that [there is a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/538462/debian-hangs-on-startup-nfs-common-utilities-statd) somewhat close to this place, but as I can't get beyond mounting the partition, I can't check this file they suggest

Answer (score 0):

If mounting the partition in a rescue environment causes a crash, then the partition is likely to be corrupted, and the underlying hardware might be failing.

The professional solution for that would be to restore from a good backup, after replacing hardware if necessary.

But if you don't have a backup, or you want to attempt to recover some important data that is `newer than your newest backup, here are some things you could do in a rescue environment without mounting the partition:

- Use `smartctl -x` on the disk in question to check it's health status.
- Check `dmesg` output to see if accessing the disk causes input/output errors
- Use `ddrescue` to image the problem partition, then try running a filesystem check on a copy of the image (as certain kinds of corruption on some filesystem types may cause worse damage). If the filesystem check fails or makes a complete mess, use other data recovery tools on the image.
- If the data on the failing partition has significant value to you, consider using professional data recovery services.

Oh, and also review your backup and restore procedures to try and improve their effectiveness.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The previous analysis with smartctl did not show any major problems. Either that or I am a noob with it. In the case of dmesg I can't find any reference to the disk, so I took the risk of mounting it. And in the 5 seconds I could get the above command:
EXT4-FS (sda1): recovery complete
EXT4-FS (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none

Comment: Those would be completely normal informative messages on mounting a ext4 file system.

Comment: ah ok, the thing is that it is the last one displayed, just before the whole operating system freezes. And when I say everything, I mean EVERYTHING, not even the keyboard responds, and when using a live, neither does the mouse.